# Map reducing algorithm

Tags: java, list, dictionary

How can I `reduce` a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`?

Let a `reduce`'d map be a map for which each `Integer` value of `List<Integer>` is unique and not duplicated.

Example:

Map A:

```
 0 --> (0)
 1 --> (1, 2) 
 2 --> (2, 1)
```

would reduce to:

```
 0 --> (0)
 1 --> (1, 2)
```

or

```
 0 --> (0)
 2 --> (2, 1)
```

Notice that either deletion of key 1 or 2 is acceptable since it produces a `reduced` map.

**EDIT**: When an element maps to itself, it should remain separate, such as `0 --> 0`. However, when multiple values have Integer's in common, they should be merged.

Comment: How would you decide which key to delete and which ones to keep ?

Comment: Well, in the above example, either key = `1` or `2` could've been deleted. Let me edit the question. The `key` deletions don't matter, it's the uniqueness and non-duplicative values that matter. P.S Why close?

Comment: What happens for  0 --> (0)
 1 --> (1, 2) 
 2 --> (2, 1, 3)

Comment: @faisal, the `reduced` map would be: `0 --> 0, 1 --> (1,2,3)` or `0 --> 0, 2 --> (2,1,3)` The order doesn't matter for the values. All that matters is the uniqueness and non-duplicativeness.

Comment: for the 1st option 0 --> 0, 1 --> (1,2,3) how come 3 be part of list1, if thats true why not ans is 0 --> (0,1,2,3)

Comment: @faisal - see edit above, please

Comment: cool, last question. What is the result for 0 --> (0) 1 --> (1, 2) 2 --> (2, 1, 3) 3-->(0)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class ReducedMap extends HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> {
    private Set<Set<Integer>> set = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();

    @Override
    public List<Integer> put(Integer key, List<Integer> value) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(value);
        if (!this.set.add(set)) {
            return new ArrayList<Integer>(set);
        }
        return super.put(key, value);
    }
      ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll look at it tomorrow after I try a few more hours.

Answer (score 0):

Keep an ArrayList, lets call it "merged".

You should use a HashSet for deteecting duplicate value. Check if an element (values in the list) is in the HashSet, if so ignore it otherwise put it in the HashSet and add it to "merged" ArrayList.

Obviously, you have to add a case at the beginning of this logic to not consider if an element maps to itself or not.

The algorithm will look like this:

1. Declare a Map> called "ret" and an ArrayList called "merged" and an HashSet called "duplicate_checker"
2. For each List in input Map

   2.1 If it maps to itself, then put it in "ret"

   2.2 Else, For each element in current List if it is not in "duplicate_checker" then put it there and add it to "merged"
3. Put "merged" to "ret"
4. return "ret"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll look at it tomorrow after I try a few more hours.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

**Version #2, the first one had a bug**.

I would use a **Pair** class, because we are going to extract all entries from the map and place them in a vector of **Pair**.

```
private static class Pair {

    public Pair(Integer k, List<Integer> l) {

        this.k = k;
        this.s = new HashSet<Integer>();
        this.s.addAll(l);
    }

    public Integer k;
    public Set<Integer> s;
}
```

Next, we need a method to check whether two sets have some elements in common.

```
public static boolean intersect(Set<Integer> a, Set<Integer> b) {

    Set<Integer> tmp = new HashSet<Integer>(a);
    tmp.retainAll(b);

    return !tmp.isEmpty();
}
```

The reduction method takes a map and returns a new, reduced, map.

```
public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> reduce(Map<Integer, List<Integer>> m) {
```

First we convert the map to an array of **Pair**; this will allow for efficient iteration and elimination of keys.

```
    int cnt = 0;
    Pair[] entries = new Pair[m.size()];

    for (Integer k : m.keySet()) {

        List<Integer> l = m.get(k);
        entries[cnt] = new Pair(k, l);
        ++cnt;
    }
```

Then we test every **Pair** against any other entry; if they have elements in common, we delete the latter but first we merge it into the former.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i) {

        for (int j = i + 1; j < m.size(); ++j) {

            if (entries[i] != null && entries[j] != null && intersect(entries[i].s, entries[j].s)) {

                Set<Integer> si = entries[i].s;
                Set<Integer> sj = entries[j].s;

                si.addAll(sj);
                entries[j] = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, we convert the array back to a map, skipping deleted elements.

```
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> r = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i)
        if (entries[i] != null)
            r.put(entries[i].k, new ArrayList<Integer>(entries[i].s));

    return r;
}
```